# How can I write text above an horizontally centered line?

Tags: graphs

I am using LaTeX and I would like to write text above a line centered horizontally to write a path from graph theory like it is done in the book *Graph Algorithms* (2nd Edition) by S. Even.

My objective is to do what is done in the last line of the fragment of the book shown in the following picture:

[image: My objective]

I would also like to be able to use an arrow instead of a line as in the following part of the same book:

[image: The same thing but with an arrow instead of a line]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! With very basic tools you could do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\hoceli}[1]{\mathrel{\dfrac{\,#1\,}{\phantom{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
$P:v_0\hoceli{e_1}v_1\hoceli{e_2}v_2$

$u\xrightarrow{\displaystyle e} v$
\end{document}
```

[image]